# finding the angle between to points with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, angle

I am making a game with pygame and i want the  player the face the cross hair, this is the code I have, I made it print out the angle in my idle and I noticed that the angles where all wrong and the player didnt rotate at all anyway. I've seen some other questions like this and I've followed them but i still get the wrong angle and the image dosnt rotate anyway

here is my code for the angle and rotating image:

```
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse_x -= crosshair.get_width() / 2
mouse_y -= crosshair.get_height() / 2
player_atan = math.atan2(player_x-player_y, mouse_x-mouse_y)
player_angle = degrees(player_atan)
pygame.transform.rotate(screen, player_angle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the python docs: it has some valuable info.

The reason why your sprite does not rotate is because rotate returns a new rotated surface.

A link to the docs:[docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html)

Comment: thats the site i have been using and I use the rotate image funtion and it dosnt work obviasly, you say the funtion returns a new rotated surface, well what does that mean?

Comment: this means that the function does not work in place, it returns a copy of the image rotated. So to rotate the image you have to assign the result of the function back to the variable. `image=rotate(image)`

Comment: ok, thanks so much for your help, just one more thing, when I run the script the players image dosnt appaer then after about 5 seconds it says width or hight is to large.

Comment: you haven't read the docs. The image is padded to hold the larger image after rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to subtract the same components from the different points.

```
player_atan = math.atan2(mouse_y - player_y, mouse_x - player_x)
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed the problem with the incorrect angles but the image still isnt rotating.

Comment: and also the top half of the numbers are negatives.

Comment: this question has not yet been anwsered. would anyone care to anwser it?

Comment: Sorry if I am a little bit picky, but the question asks about angles, and that has indeed been answered. I'd say you have another problem now, the image is not being rotated.

Comment: I mentond that in my question

Comment: pygame.transform.rotate(Surface, angle)

Comment: that line dosnt rotat the image

Comment: That returns the rotated surface. See example: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/RotateCenter?parent=CookBook